# MongoDB aggregate $group shows no result

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I want to group all the data with startDate>=today-3 or <=today+3. Here is the database:

```
 "startDate": {
"$date": "2024-03-05T00:00:00Z" }
```

Here is the query:

```
const dailyPlans = await DailyPlan.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: { $in: allPlansID },
      startDate: {
        $gte: startUtcDate,
        $lte: endUtcDate,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: {
            $toDate: "$startDate",
          },
        },
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: And I can get proper result if I only use find to match:
const dailyPlans_0 = await DailyPlan.find({
      _id: { $in: allPlansID },
          startDate: {
            $gte: new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate() - 3),
            $lte: new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate() + 3),
          },
    })

Answer (score 2):

This is how your $group stage should look like:
([here is the correct syntaxt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#syntax))

```json
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$startDate",
        },
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
```

In your aggregate query, you're using `$toDate` to convert the `startDate` field to a date object. However, it seems unnecessary because `startDate` is already stored as a date object I assume based on your `DailyPlan.find(query)` in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria looks like a `$and` criteria to me. You can leave all the date processing to `$dateAdd`/`$dateSubtract`. `$dateTrunc` can be used to make `$$NOW`, which refers to current datetime, to date only.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              "$startDate",
              {
                "$dateSubtract": {
                  "startDate": {
                    $dateTrunc: {
                      date: "$$NOW",
                      unit: "day"
                    }
                  },
                  "unit": "day",
                  "amount": 3
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              "$startDate",
              {
                "$dateAdd": {
                  "startDate": {
                    $dateTrunc: {
                      date: "$$NOW",
                      unit: "day"
                    }
                  },
                  "unit": "day",
                  "amount": 3
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m6HNEmaJ7Km)

Comment: but `$and` is implicit with multiple conditions provided

Comment: @GarrGodfrey What do you mean?

Comment: I mean `startDate: { $gte: startUtcDate, $lte: endUtcDate}` does the same thing as `{$and: [{startDate: {$gte: startUtcDate}}, {startDate: {$lte: endUtcDate}}]}`

Comment: @GarrGodfrey yes you are right. But my solution involves the usage of `$dateAdd` and `$dateSubtract` so they need to be wrapped inside `$expr`. The concise syntax you mentioned cannot be applied with `$expr` in this specific case.